# Do I have to mount new partitions in /mnt

Tags: mount

I mounted a new SSD drive under `/mnt/sdc1`. I then symlinked various folders that have been taking up a lot of space in my `/home` directory to that partition, so I could free up some storage in `/home`, for example:

`ln -s /mnt/sdc1/downloads ~/downloads`

or

`ln -s /mnt/sdc1/videos ~/videos`

But that got me thinking. Would I be able to just make a folder for it in my `/home` directory and then mount it there? Is mounting drives in `/mnt` just convention or does mounting a new drive anywhere else actually have any consequences and cause trouble later down the line?

Comment: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s12.html . /mnt is hinted to be for temporary use, but I guess some distributions or people will have an other opinion.

Comment: @A.B *Sub specie aeternitatis* all mounts are temporary. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounting in `/mnt` is just convention and it is *definitely* not required, especially for permanent mounts.

For your use case, it might actually be ideal to mount your SSD somewhere outside `/mnt`, but not in the way you're doing it. Refer to the diagram below.

[image: Instead of symlinking into /home, you can just put /home on the SSD.]

This is a very common way to set up a partitions under Linux. [GParted](https://gparted.org/) is a very useful tool for changing your partition layout, as you can edit and format partitions at the same time. You might have to manually edit fstab yourself, though; I highly recommend using UUIDs (or PARTUUIDs on GPT partition tables) to identify disks in /etc/fstab.